# how to prevent code duplication in android

Tags: java, android, oop, android-volley

I am new to android and OOP. I know one of Fowler's bad smells is code duplication. I have about 25 volley requests in my whole projects in different activities, and in all of them, there is a 90% same code.

Look at this pseudo code:

```
on Error:
    if no connection:
        Toast "no connection"
    else if no response:
        Toast "server error"
    else
        show popup with a retry button which will call the function which this request is inside it again.
```

My first question is how to write these in one place and use the whole request object in different places.

My second question is there are some activity-related codes in some special activities. For example, on my login page I have no *unauthorized* error but in other pages I have. Or as you see, In my last *else* in the above code, I have said recall the function and if every request it different. How can I handle that?

How should I do that?
Is there any special reference?
tnx

Comment: If that is all then no need to change things.

Comment: I think the big "smell" in the above code would be repeating all the popup code each time you use it.  Maybe you can move it to a common helper method.  Honestly, your Android code may have some boiler plating to it.

Comment: @greenapps my problems is that at first I used popups for no connection error, but then I decided to show toasts, which made me change 20 25 codes. So I thought I may change some designs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using android built-in popups which I assume I have no simple way to use them. If there is any I would be grateful to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an util class to create the request.
For example this is a class able to create a GET request using `JSONObject` that display Toast messages on error, and execute the function that you pass as paramter on success:

```
public class VolleyUtils{


public static JsonObjectRequest createGetRequest(String url, Consumer<? super JSONObject> successCallback){

    return new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            successCallback.consume(response)
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                VolleyUtils.showToast("No Internet connection");
            } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                VolleyUtils.showToast("Bad authentication");
            } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                VolleyUtils.showToast("Error with server");
            } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                VolleyUtils.showToast("Network error");
            } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                VolleyUtils.showToast("Parsing Error");
            }
        }
    });

}


private static void showToast(String errorText){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

So, for create a new request, you just need this:

```
//supposing you get the RequestQueue with Singleton Pattern
MySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(VolleyUtils.createGetRequest("www.google.com", (JSONObject response) -> { 
        //stuff to do when request has success, for example :
        myTextView.setText(response.toString())

    } ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing duplication of code, Put your code in a function (with or without argument, its depend on your task requirement) and call it where you want in your program.

If you have no idea how to make a function in Android or java Please follow this link
http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions